# Выполнить набор SQL DDL команд на основе списка кортежей (ключ, таблица)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Имеется запрос с выводом вида:

```
[('table_fkey', 'table'), ('table2_fkey', 
'tsble2'), ('table3_fkey', 'table3'),....('tableN_fkey', 'tableN')]
```

Как выполнить запрос для каждой пары списка?

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP CONSTRAINT table_fkey;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сгенерируйте соответствующие SQL комманды и выполните их:

```
from psycopg2 import connect, sql

conn_info = "dbname=db port=5432 host=127.0.0.1"

conn = connect(conn_info)

alter_tab_pat = 'ALTER TABLE {} DROP CONSTRAINT {}'

items = [('table_fkey', 'table'), ('table2_fkey', 'tsble2'), 
         ('table3_fkey', 'table3'),('tableN_fkey', 'tableN')]

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    for key,tab in items:
        cur.execute(sql.SQL(alter_tab_pat).format(
            sql.Identifier(tab), sql.Identifier(key))
        )

conn.close()
```

PS [psycopg2.sql.Identifier](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) позволяет защититься от [SQL Injections](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

PPS [Обычная SQL параметризация](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) здесь не сработает т.к. параметризировать можно только литералы и значения, но не имена объектов (таблиц, столбцов, ключей, индексов и т.д.)